# jquery Ajax response "undefined" with Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, undefined

I've got a situation with jquery ajax requests.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        cache: false, 
        url: "/ajax/script.php",
        data: { display: 'user', user_id: '1'}
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        if (msg !== "") {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

With Chrome & Firefox I've html code generate by the script `/ajax/script.php`
With IE8 (I've not tried with 6, 7 and 9+) I have `Undefined`

Do someone knows how to fix that?

**Edit:** I'm using jquery 1.7.2

Comment: I got the same issue. Answer below is incorrect, it doesn't fix anything. In Network tab whenever I make an SQL query I see correct data being sent and correct data received. Still though the msg variable is undefined in IE. Everything else works correctly.

Comment: This issue is also apperant in IE9 .. Trust IE to spoil the day. There are quite strict requirements for IE so i would advise checking in chrome your headers : Content charsets being sent back etc.. Im having the same problem and im close to burning all evidence of IE on the planet.

Answer (score 4):

Returning the MIMEType of `application/json; charset=utf8` caused this same behavior for me in IE8. Changing it to `application/json;` made IE8 magically start functioning.

Comment: I waded through thousands of stackoverflow posts and your's finally helped. Thanks! :)

Comment: You are the savior of man kind. This answer is the right/best answer. I doubted other best parts of my application because of this stupid IE. I have to go and apologize to all of my good piece of coding.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you don't define "msg" it is undefined.
done() expects a function, multiple functionsor nothing as arguments.

If you want a callback from you ajax call, you should use

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        cache: false, 
        dataType: 'text',
        url: "/ajax/script.php",
        data: { display: 'user', user_id: '1'},
        success: function(data) {
            // do something
        }

    });
```

**Edit:** I'm using jquery 1.7.2 if it can help

Comment: well, alert(data) still returns "Undefined" with IE8 :s

Comment: Are you sure the script returns something?

Comment: with Chrome or Firefox I've html generated by script.php

Comment: could you tell us what is returned i Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: right now in script.php I've put: <?php print_r($_POST); ?> So with firefox and chrome I got Array ( [display] => user [user_id] => 1 ) and with IE: Undefined

Comment: Since you expect an json object, try telling that with datatype (I edited it in).

Comment: I'm not expecting a json object. moreover I still have the same issue

Comment: OK, have you tried 'text' or 'html'? Also why are you using async: false?

Comment: I still have "undefined" with text or html. I'm using async: false because I read on a topic that async:false could help to resolve the problem with IE. But actually no ^^

Comment: have you tried visiting the page /ajax/script.php with you IE8? I'm sorry I couldn't help. If you haven't done so already I'd probably try calling the whole thing not from $(document).ready but from a click event or so...

Comment: when I visit the page script.php it's working properly. I also tried with a click event but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem changing code from:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
```

to:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```