# Internet explorer passes undefined to success callback when fetching 30MB of data or more

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a problem with fetching JSON data from server in Internet explorer. I am using standard jquery ajax call to the server to retrieve binary data representing file, which is then opened in FlowPaper's PDF viewer. Everything is OK for files of sizes up to 20MB. When I try to get data for files with size 30MB and up, the call comes back as successfull, but data sent to success callback is undefined. This behavior happens in Internet explorer only, but in Chrome or Opera everything works for all file sizes.

JS code is straightforward and simple

```
var id = "documentID";
var url = 'API/GetDocumentURL';
var data = JSON.stringify({ 
    "DocumentID": id
});
var type = 'POST';
var async = true;
var success = function (data) {
    debugger; // in IE data is undefined, other browsers have results stored in this variable
};
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    async: async,
    data: data,
    success: success
});
```

Jquery version is 1-8-2, but I have a feeling that this is more a problem of Internet explorer, and not Jquery. Internet explorer version is 11.

Does anyone have any idea why Internet explorer is firing success callback, but not passing in the data retrieved with AJAX call?

Comment: You said it's not working in IE but have you also tested the script behavior in Chrome and FF? Some JSONSerialiser may have a limit on the maximum size or structure, which would also be dependent on the used browser.

Comment: Yep. troed om Chrome and Opera

Answer (score 0):

Returning the MIMEType of application/json; charset=utf8 caused this same behavior for me in IE8. Changing it to application/json; made IE8 magically start functioning. Check what your server is returning for a MIMEType and see if fiddling with that is causing an issue.

Edit: Actually what was causing the real problem is that it should be charset=utf-8 and not as shown above without the hyphen.

For more infor [jquery Ajax response "undefined" with Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139957/jquery-ajax-response-undefined-with-internet-explorer)